# How to manage xml content at nopcommerce backend?

Tags: nopcommerce

I have a question about manage a xml file at the backend.

At the home page, there is a flash, and this flash request a xml file(It will contains some images url or video file url), and client want to manage this xml file at the backend.

I wondering is that possible? If so, how? Please show me the detail or some links.

I try to using "topic" to do this, but it only have a rich text box editor, and it's too hard to input xml content for a normal user.

Any help is appreciate.

I use NopCommerce 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with NopCommerce 1.9 because it has no facility to organise data islands of any kind.

The simple option is to configure an FTP account so that the user could upload XML if they do indeed understand it.

The other way is to add your own admin page. For simple XML settings, you don't need to alter the database.

1. Start by adding a new setting, e.g. "XML.HomepageFlash", you can preset this to some working XML config. Note that you can add the entry via the admin area or via direct database edit.
2. Add a new page to the "/admin" folder and build your configuration form (if all you need is a plain text editor, then that's quite easy). Obviously write it to load and save to your new setting via a Nop SettingsManager instance. You should derive this page from an existing admin page to match the style.
3. Update the admin sitemap file to include your new page.
4. Finally, you'll need to pipe the XML settings to the flash control, so write a simple page that loads the data and writes it out as an XML file (make sure that you change the contenttype to text/xml).

A final thought - if you intend to let the webmaster edit xml themselves, then you could skip steps 2 and 3, and just let them edit the xml in the settings area of configuration.

I hope that this gives you a few pointers.

Mark